# How to move one directory back in unix / linux when path contains symbolic links?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, symlink, cd

I have created a symbolic link to a deeply nested directory. Using symbolic link i can move to that directory from my home directory. I want to move one directory back from the target directory but the shell comes back to the home directory.

```
[root@pe1800xs ~]# pwd
/root

[root@pe1800xs ~]# mkdir -p abc/def/ghi/jkl/mno/pqr

[root@pe1800xs ~]# ln -s abc/def/ghi/jkl/mno/pqr/ xyz

[root@pe1800xs ~]# cd xyz

[root@pe1800xs xyz]# pwd
/root/xyz

[root@pe1800xs xyz]# pwd -P
/root/abc/def/ghi/jkl/mno/pqr

[root@pe1800xs xyz]# cd ..

[root@pe1800xs ~]# pwd
/root
```

What I want to achieve is that when I do `cd..` in `pqr` directory the shell should come to `mno` directory.

Comment: links in unix act like the files were direct there so naturaly cd..  goes up in the hierarchy like the file were there  you can  create a link to /root/abc/def/ghi/jkl/mno in the pqr directory and then just cd to it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must use

```
cd -P xyz
```

to enter into that directory to follow the original structure of folders, then you can move as you wish because you have resolved the link to the real path.

Answer (score 7):

You have to pass `-P` option:

```
cd -P ..
```